# connecting C# with Oracle database

Tags: c#

I have C# and Oracle 10g installed on my workstation.And also created a C# program,so my problem is i cant connent my C# application with Oracle database.it is really freaking me out.when adding Reference i cant find "Oracle.DataAccess.dll".thnx in advance.#Amu

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed ODAC (oracle client) components on you workstation?

If you would use Oracle.Data namespace You need them. You can download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Please chek database version and bitness, because it is an important factor.

If you dont want to install Oracle client, you could try to use System.Data.OracleClient namespace, that's bundled with framework. In this case take in account that's deprecated and will be removed on next version of framework ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.oracleclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))